# How to stop javascript filter function earlier to optimize

Tags: javascript, performance

```
const filtered = array_of_things.filter(thing => {

  const isCar = thing.item === 'car'
  const colorIsRed = thing.color === 'red'
  const isSUV = thing.type === 'SUV'
  const priceIsHigh = thing.price >= 100
  const widthIsTen = thing.width === 10

  return isCar && colorIsRed && isSUV && priceIsHigh && widthIsTen 
})
```

So in my example code, the code keeps going through even if the first comparison is false. How do I make it so it ends at the first false and doesn't make rest of the comparisons?

Also is this better than calling a filter on each comparison? Having multiple filters like:

```
  const filter_SUV = array_of_things.filter(thing => thing.type === 'SUV')
  const filter_red = filter_SUV.filter(thing => thing.color === 'red')
```

Comment: Are you just trying to find the first instance of one of the values?

Comment: so do not do the comparison in a variable.... do it in the return?

Comment: when you say early break, `filter` is not the right function here.

Answer (score 1):

Don't create separate variables, simply return each condition `&&`d with each other condition:

```
const filtered = array_of_things.filter(({ item, color, type, price, width }) => (
  item === 'car' &&
  color === 'red' &&
  type === 'SUV' &&
  price >= 100 &&
  width === 10
));
```

Yes, this sort of pattern is slightly more efficient than calling `.filter` multiple times, because a single `.filter` means that the array is only iterated over once.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question

Comment: Sure it does, if any of the conditions are false, the next conditions will not be evaluated at all.

Comment: ok this is what i was looking for. Thanks. 
Sorry @MiguelCoder if my question was confusing.